# hyperlink to an embeded pdf

Tags: hyperref, pdf, embedding

I found a way to embed a PDF and provide a hyperlink to it using `hypgotoe`. So, this is similar to what I am currently doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}
\embedfile{/home/pavan/test.pdf}
\begin{document}
\href{gotoe:embedded=/home/pavan/test.pdf}{description}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I am not able to get the hyperlink. I see "description" in my final PDF but there is no hyperlink that links my embedded file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you are using a PDF viewer that does not support `GoToE` links.

Comment: Ah, now that you mention I noticed that when I use Okular to view the file, there isn't a hyperlink but I get a prompt to save and view the embedded file at the beginning. And, when I used document viewer I see a hyperlink but it open my embedded file. Any work around? Is there any other way to embed files so that it works irrespective of what I use to view the pdf?

Comment: _It is PDF viewer dependent:_ A test worked fine here with Adobe Reader, but neither with PDF-Xchange Viewer nor SumatraPDF.