# Cannot open an embedded pdf

Tags: texstudio, viewers, embedding, linuxfedora, embedfile

I am using TexStudio in Fedora 29. 
This piece of code seemed to compile correctly 
but the embedded pdf does not open if I click on the hyperlink...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embedfile}
\usepackage{hypgotoe}
\embedfile{myfile.pdf}
\begin{document}
\href{gotoe:embedded=myfile.pdf}{description}
\end{document}
```

There seems to be similar question and the resolution was that it is "PDF viewer dependent". That does not help me much. I could not install Adobe Acrobat on my distribution. With Evince, Foxit and Atril it does not work. Ocular seems to detect embedded file (and asks me to save them) but does not open the hyperlink. Any ideas what I could do view those embeddings when I click on the hyperlink word?

[hyperlink to an embeded pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88029/hyperlink-to-an-embeded-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

With your code as it stands I can open the embedment from the bookmark (ToC). But not from the description. This is a problem area as there are several ways the embedment may be referenced so in this case it seems to take on the name of the main document with a suffix but not build an inline hyperref , thus you may want to look at that package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative package called `attachfile` which might be more appropriate for your use case.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.txt}
Text.
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\begin{document}
\textattachfile{myfile.txt}{Click here to access myfile.txt}
\end{document}
```